# setting rpmforge repository for Linux (RHEL)

Tags: centos, redhat, amavis

I had a Linux centos(5.5) machine, on this i had deployed amavisd (with clamav and spamassassin).
Referred these:

http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/Amavisd

http://wiki.centos.org/PackageManagement/Yum/Priorities

Now I have a linux RHEL machine, details are as follows:

(Linux version 2.6.18-164.6.1.el5 (mockbuild@ls20-bc2-14.build.redhat.com) (gcc version 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-46)) x86_64 GNU/Linux Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.5 (Tikanga))

I want to set up the above mentioned software's on this(RHEL) machine, for that I do (as per the reference link):

```
install yum-priorities
```

but i am unable to install this on my said machine, because the default yum repository provided by RHEL doesn't contain this.

How can i deploy the above software's on my RHEL machine, suggest any safe alternate.

Please guide since i am a newbie in this matter.

thanks in advance
Ashish Sharma

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will probably need to download the CentOS source rpm for yum-priorities and build it for your RHEL system.

Comment: RHEL and CentOS are binary-compatible. Rebuilding will not be necessary.